# When does 可 before a verb mean “willing to”, and when does it mean “can”?

Tags: grammar

In a sentence like this,

他遇到了一个好朋友, 可带他去很多酒吧

does the 可 mean the new friend “can” bring him to the bar, or that he is “willing to”?

I’ve always thought of 可 as just “can” or “able to”, but I saw on Pleco that it could be used as an auxiliary to mean “be willing to; be ready to”.

The examples given include 可干 and 可虚心接受意见.

Maybe it always means “willing to” in front of a verb, and you’d use 可以 when you want to say “can”?

Comment: 他遇到了一个好朋友, 可带他去很多酒吧 isn't a good sentence.  where did you see the sentence?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I saw a similarly structured sentence in a webnovel synopsis, but didn’t want to copy it, so tweaked it instead.  The main point is that he met a person that can take him through to another world.  I couldn’t think of a different scenario where the same structure might be used, hence the bad sentence.  Please excuse it.  (._.;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

可虚心接受意见 literally mean "can/ able to humbly accept suggestions"

If you **can accept** suggestions, it also implies you are willing to accept suggestions (most people can't accept suggestions = unwilling to accept suggestions)

可带他去很多酒吧 should be translated as 'able to take him to many bars'

For 可 to suggest 'willing', the sentence must state something the subject might be unwilling to do

Example:

這孩子**可**刻苦練功 (This child **can** practice hard) meaning 這孩子**肯** (willing to) 刻苦練功   (most people can't practice hard = unwilling to practice hard)

it is better to replace 可 (can/ able/ *willing to*) with the more specific 肯 for "willing"

Answer (score 1):

他遇到了一个好朋友, 可带他去很多酒吧 isn't an idiomatic sentence.

I will understand it as *he might take him to many bars*.  可 in the context means 可以 or 可能，may or can.